# Issue while running Spark Streaming with IBM MQ

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, spark-streaming, ibm-mq

I'm trying to pull messages from IBMMQ using Spark Streaming , its running fine using IDE but on executing the same code on cluster the below exception is thrown.

Exception obtained while using spark-submit.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnection
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Have included all the jars relevant in the class path (mq, mqjms, dhbcore, jmqi) but still getting the exception.

Did anyone face similar issue?

Comment: What version is listed in each jar you included.   Is it possible jar files with conflicting versions are in the classpath?

Comment: @JoshMc Yes,was able to resolve the issue,it was because of the Jar conflicts and some dependency jars missing.